# Neural Network: Issues in using my finding and using my train data in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, matlab

I am trying to train a neural network for my certain values. The whole scenario is this that i have written a code in matlab that finds out the mean values of frames and max and min points for each frame for a certain video. Basically i am extracting features. Now i need to put these values to a neural network and train them, but i dont know how to use neural networks. I have several articles on this but the main issues with my understanding are

1) I dont know what to put in the target matrix as as per my output, the value should appear in the targets field that asks to take it from workspace. I dont find the mean, min or max variable thr :( . I tried to put an image of pattern recognition toolbox of matlab to make my point clear but i cant post images yet

2) My data is dynamic, i.e my values are computed on run time and i want to feed it to the neural network at run time. Can any one plz tell me how which matlab neural network tool to use in this scenario? In every tool, I can not put my data into targets. Please guide me that how targets should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should figure out what kind of problem you're dealing with here. You said you're extracting features from frames of a video. OK. Now, what do you want to do with these features?

Basically, I can think of two kinds of problems that proceeds feature extraction:

1. **Recognition (Detection) :** In this scenario, you extract features to compare them against existing ones to find matches for specific purposes.
   Here, the neural network is trained to give the proper output when the input feature vector is matched with the one that the network is trained on (e.g 1 if it's matched and 0 if otherwise). A simple example for this would be finding faces in each frame of the video.
2. **Classification :** Here, there's no matching happening. You want to classify feature vectors into different classes. You'll use the NN to do the classification and the output would be the class assigned to each feature vector. For example, you want to find out how many of the frames in the video has light backgrounds and how many has dark ones.

So, based on the type of the problem, the type of the NN you'll end up using will differ and consequently, the target(output) that you need.

Hope it clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Mine prb is the 1st one. I need to recognize and match the patterns. Basically i need to see that if the same video is being played or not. I am doing it on basis of features extracted. What i get from your explanation is that input feature is used as a target? or otherwise, what data i need to put in my targets vector? Basically I am some what totally blank on this concept so if u can guide me accordingly.

Comment: Well...if you want to match 2 videos, I don't recommend using NN at all. NN is good for matching shapes or objects, but you have many frames and if you want to use NN, you should train a NN for each frame which is infeasible. I googled and came across this paper for fast video matching. It seems to give a good approach to this. Take a look, it may be useful: http://lbmedia.ece.ucsb.edu/resources/ref/civr09.pdf

Comment: I have recognized it with neural networks. My main issue was that i was not understanding the syntax of matlab of neural networks. I have done it using multiple features and pass it to train in NN

Comment: Well, glad it was sorted out for you. :) Just out of curiosity, are you aggregating the features of all(samples) frames and passing it to NN? i.e one feature vector for all the frames?

Comment: yes I am aggregating the features. My main issue was that i couldnot get the concept of targets and predicted output in matlab. I have collected all the features in a single file and used it for training of two classes.

Comment: Just an addition to my comment... i used nprtool to match the patterns ... it gave way better results .... matlab nprtool has the option to generate an advanced code from which u can modify the parameters...

Comment: I can't... don have 15 rep points yet :) if anyone finds my ans useful and will upvote that... i'll surely do urs :)